# Props being parsed undefined?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Have this very simple vue component where I am trying to accept a search string as a prop

```
Vue.component('search-person', {
        props: ['searchStr'],
        created(){
            console.log(this)
        },
        template:  `<div class="container">
                        <form class="search-person-form">
                            <input type="text" class="search-person-input" placeholder="Search person" v-model="searchStr">
                            <div v-if="!searchStr.length">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="search-person-icon">
                                <title>Search</title>
                                    <path d="M32 31.060l-12.233-12.24c1.777-1.992 2.863-4.634 2.863-7.53 0-6.259-5.074-11.333-11.333-11.333s-11.333 5.074-11.333 11.333c0 6.259 5.074 11.333 11.333 11.333 2.896 0 5.538-1.086 7.541-2.873l-0.011 0.010 12.233 12.24zM1.293 11.333c0-5.523 4.477-10 10-10s10 4.477 10 10c0 5.509-4.454 9.977-9.958 10h-0.002c-0 0-0 0-0 0-5.531 0-10.017-4.472-10.040-9.998v-0.002z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else >
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="search-person-icon pointer">
                                    <title>cross</title>
                                    <path d="M26 6.96l-0.96-0.96-9.040 9.040-9.040-9.040-0.96 0.96 9.040 9.040-9.040 9.040 0.96 0.96 9.040-9.040 9.040 9.040 0.96-0.96-9.040-9.040 9.040-9.040z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>`
    })
```

I am then trying to use the component and parse a search string that is part of the data as a prop

```
<search-person :searchStr="personSearchStr"/>
```

personSearchStr is a part of the data object of the component that is nesting the search-person component but in my search-person component the searchStr prop is undefined

Comment: Can you post more code on how `personSearchStr` is populated and are you sure it has a value when it's being passed in to this other component?

Comment: @maxshuty Will update the post in a bit but personSearchStr is set as an empty string initially in the return of the data method that is inside of the component that is nesting the searchStr component. It then tries to parse the empty personSearchStr as a prop so it can bind it as an input there.

Comment: @nikulasokarsson so set `personSearchStr` to a hardcoded value of `'test'` or something and then what happens?

Comment: @maxshuty It's still undefined

Comment: Can you please create a code pen for this issue, that will really help to solve the issue faster

Comment: Also, instead of binding the prop to the input ```<input type="text"  v-model = "searchStr">```, try binding the input to a new data element initialized from the prop:  ```data() { return {localSearchString: this.searchStr }}```. Then bind ```<input type="text"  v-model = "localSearchStr">```.  That way you are not mutating the prop.

Comment: @Tim Hmm okay, What if I want to change the original personSearchStr since I have some data in the component where it's declared where I want to filter through it based on what is in the string?

Comment: @nikulasoskarsson You are welcome.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, I created an example scenario with a Search Input component and it's Parent container.

The initial value of the search input (child) comes from a prop set in the parent.  The search input watches the prop, so when the parent value is changed (via an input in the parent in my example), the child updates it's local copy.  This happens as the user types (no form submission in parent).

When the search input (child) value is changed and the child form is submitted, an event is emitted to send the child value to update the parent.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent Component</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="prop-value">Enter new prop value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prop-value" v-model="parentSearch">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <search-input :searchFromParent="parentSearch" @update-search-event="updateSearch" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import SearchInput from './SearchInput.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      SearchInput
    },
    data() {
      return {
        parentSearch: 'Search value from parent prop'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateSearch(searchFromChild) {
        this.parentSearch = searchFromChild;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

SearchInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="search-input">
    <h5>Search Input Component (child)</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" v-model="localSearch">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit search value to parent</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      searchFromParent: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        localSearch: this.searchFromParent
      }
    },
    watch: {
      searchFromParent(newValue) {
        this.localSearch = newValue;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm() {
        this.$emit('update-search-event', this.localSearch)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```